# Is there any way that I can simplify my code using a loop. in Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, refactoring

I have a program that looks at votes entered for candidates and determines the winner by who has the lowest score. Because the user enters their preferences from 1 to 5 with 1 being the favorite and 5 being the least favorite. If there is a draw the candidate with the most 1's win, if this is still a draw then its the candidate with the most 2's. I have a program but want to know if I can simplify it before I continue to repeat the code to check who got the most 2's ect. This is what I have so far.

```
    If candidate1 < candidate2 And candidate1 < candidate3 And candidate1 < candidate4 And candidate1 < candidate5 Then
        MsgBox("The winner is" & LblCand1.Text)
    ElseIf candidate2 < candidate1 And candidate2 < candidate3 And candidate2 < candidate4 And candidate2 < candidate5 Then
        MsgBox("The winner is" & lblCand2.Text)
    ElseIf candidate3 < candidate2 And candidate3 < candidate1 And candidate3 < candidate4 And candidate3 < candidate5 Then
        MsgBox("The winner is" & lblCand3.Text)
    ElseIf candidate4 < candidate2 And candidate4 < candidate3 And candidate4 < candidate1 And candidate4 < candidate5 Then
        MsgBox("The winner is" & lblCand4.Text)
    ElseIf candidate5 < candidate2 And candidate5 < candidate3 And candidate5 < candidate4 And candidate5 < candidate1 Then
        MsgBox("The winner is" & lblCand5.Text)
    ElseIf C1V1s > C2V1s And C1V1s > C3V1s And C1V1s > C4V1s And C1V1s > C5V1s Then
        MsgBox("The winner is" & LblCand1.Text)
    ElseIf C2V1s > C1V1s And C2V1s > C3V1s And C2V1s > C4V1s And C2V1s > C5V1s Then
        MsgBox("The winner is" & lblCand2.Text)
    ElseIf C3V1s > C1V1s And C3V1s > C2V1s And C3V1s > C4V1s And C3V1s > C5V1s Then
        MsgBox("The winner is" & lblCand3.Text)
    ElseIf C4V1s > C1V1s And C4V1s > C2V1s And C4V1s > C3V1s And C4V1s > C5V1s Then
        MsgBox("The winner is" & lblCand4.Text)
    ElseIf C5V1s > C1V1s And C5V1s > C2V1s And C5V1s > C3V1s And C5V1s > C4V1s Then
        MsgBox("The winner is" & lblCand5.Text)
    End If
```

Comment: It looks like you ought to go and read about collections, rather than the use of individual variables for everything.

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend that you create a class `Candidate` which contains a score and a name for each candidate:

```
Class Candidate
    Implements IComparable(Of Candidate)

    Public Property Score As Integer
    Public Property Name As String

    Public Function CompareTo(other As Candidate) As Integer Implements IComparable(Of Candidate).CompareTo
        If (other.Score > Me.Score) Then
            Return -1
        ElseIf (other.Score = Me.Score) Then
            Return 0
        Else
            Return 1
        End If
    End Function
End Class
```

Then, if you have a collection of your candidate instances, you can do the following:

```
Dim myCandidates As New List(Of Candidate)
'fill your list with instances somehow...
MsgBox(String.Format("The winner is {0}", myCandidates.Min().Name))
```

Note that the `Candidate` class has to implement [the IComparable(Of T) interface](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4d7sx9hd%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) so the instances know how to compare themselves from the `Min()` method.